# How to seed player name and score into database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, post, seed

I am building an scoreboard web app with angular that posts player's names and scores.  I would like to seed data before the application runs, however I am only able to seed their name if it is listed as a string within an array like so:

```
var players = [
  'Bob',
  'Tom',
  'Mark'
];
```

I would like to seed the player's name and score using an object inside an array like so:

```
var players = [
  {"name": "Mary", "score": 9},
  {"name": "Barry", "score": 16},
  {"name": "Harry", "score": 12}
];
```

Below is my function that is posting the player's name and score of '0' instead of their score inside the object listed above.  I only want a new player to receive a score of '0'.

**seed.js**

```
players.forEach(function (player, index) {
  Player.find({ 'name': player},
   function(err, players) {
    if (!err && !players.length) {
      Player.create({ score: 0, name: player });
    }
  });
});

This is the model that I created in MongoDB for the player:
```

**player.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  score: Number
});

var model = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

Here is my html for the player:

**player.html**

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy: 'player.score' ">
  <label ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing=true">{{player.name}}</label>
  <input ng-show="editing" ng-blur="editing = false" class="editing-label" type="text" ng-model="player.name" ng-change="player.edited = true"/>
  <div class="actions">
    <button ng-model="player.score" min="0" ng-click="player.score = player.score - 1" type="number" >-</button>
    <label ng-model="player.score" placeholder="0" class="editing-label">{{player.score}}</label>
    <button ng-model="player.score" min="0" ng-click="player.score = player.score + 1" type="number">+</button>
    <a href="" ng-click="savePlayers()">Save</a>
    <a href="" class="delete" ng-click="deletePlayer(player, $index)">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of how my app looks currently:

[image: Current]

Here is a picture of how I would like my app to look:

[image: Desired]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you just do `Player.insertMany(players, callback)`? Because that's how I seed my database on app start. I have an external JSON file that I parse in and insert the elements into my database.

Answer (score 0):

When you seed, generally you will want to drop the data in your database beforehand, so there wouldn't be any players already in the database--this means you don't have to worry about whether or not they exist already as you seed.

If this is the case, you can write your seed.js like so, simply creating each player from your array:

```
Player.remove({}, function(err) {
  //this will remove all the players from your table
  if(err) console.error(err);
  else {
    players.forEach(function (player) {
      //player is an object with both the name and score
      Player.create(player, function(err, createdPlayer) {
        if(err) console.error(err);
        else console.log('player was created!', createdPlayer);
      });
    });
  }
})
```

If you wish to not drop your entries each time you reseed, you can use the code you already have, but if you don't find the player in your database, you can create it using the player object from your array:

```
players.forEach(function (player) {
  Player.find({name: player.name },
   function(err, players) {
    if (!err && !players.length) {
      Player.create(player, function(err) {
        if(err) console.error(err); //always handle your errors, just in case!
      });
    }
  });
});
```